# get headers from table with bcp command

Tags: php, sql, bcp

I use bcp utility to get header with having parameter of table and database but as table I can not get header with cast in sql command in php.

query is as below

```
$cmd = 'bcp "select \'*\' union all  SELECT cast(*) as varchar(255) FROM ['.$database.'].[dbo].['.$table.']" queryout "d:\[dir]...\'.$database.'_'.$table.'.csv" -T -c -t, -S tvt24';
```

How can I get headers of multiple table as argument?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `CAST(*)` is meaningless, and an error. Did you mean to do `SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS VARCHAR(255))`?

Comment: Please post an example of the output this produces.  It seems highly likely you could produce it in PHP natively without having to make the system call to `bcp`. In any case, we need more information about what you're trying to accomplish.